# Proton CEP Absence EPA not triggered

Tags: fiware

I am unable to get ProtonCEP to create an event based on an absence rule.

The EPA "MissingQueueDataRule" is supposed to create an event "MissingQueueData" in the case that no events of type "QueueContextUpdate" (the entityID of the event is not important) are received in a past time interval (30 seconds).

There are no visible errors in the logs.

```
{
 "epn": {
    "events": [
      {
        "name": "Device",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "datacount5",
            "type": "Integer",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "The certainty that this event happen (value between 0 to 1)"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Queue",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "volume",
            "type": "Integer",
            "dimension": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "DeviceContextUpdate",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "datacount5m",
            "type": "Integer",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "The certainty that this event happen (value between 0 to 1)"
          },
          {
            "name": "entityId",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "entityType",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "lastupdate",
            "type": "Date",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "activationdate",
            "type": "Date",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "efficiencyratio",
            "type": "Double",
            "dimension": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "QueueContextUpdate",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "volume",
            "type": "Integer",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "entityId",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "entityType",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "QueueVolumeHigh",
        "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "Certainty",
            "type": "Double",
            "defaultValue": "1",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "The certainty that this event happen (value between 0 to 1)"
          },
          {
            "name": "OccurrenceTime",
            "type": "Date",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "No value means it equals the event detection time, other option is to use one of the defined distribution functions with parameters"
          },
          {
            "name": "ExpirationTime",
            "type": "Date",
            "dimension": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "Cost",
            "type": "Double",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "The cost of this event occurrence. Negative if this is an opportunity"
          },
          {
            "name": "Duration",
            "type": "Double",
            "defaultValue": "0",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "Used in case the this event occur within an interval"
          },
          {
            "name": "AffectedEntity",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "AffectedEntityType",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "EventType",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "EventSeverity",
            "type": "String",
            "dimension": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "AffectedEntityVolume",
            "type": "Integer",
            "dimension": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "MissingQueueData",
        "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "Certainty",
            "type": "Double",
            "defaultValue": "1",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "The certainty that this event happen (value between 0 to 1)"
          },
          {
            "name": "OccurrenceTime",
            "type": "Date",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "No value means it equals the event detection time, other option is to use one of the defined distribution functions with parameters"
          },
          {
            "name": "ExpirationTime",
            "type": "Date",
            "dimension": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "Cost",
            "type": "Double",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "The cost of this event occurrence. Negative if this is an opportunity"
          },
          {
            "name": "Duration",
            "type": "Double",
            "defaultValue": "0",
            "dimension": 0,
            "description": "Used in case the this event occur within an interval"
          },
          {
            "name": "EventSeverity",
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "\"Warning\"",
            "dimension": "0"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "epas": [
      {
        "name": "CriticalQueueVolumeRule",
        "description": "Emit a QueueVolumeHigh with Severity=Critical if any Queue volume > 1000",
        "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
        "createdBy": "Pedro",
        "epaType": "All",
        "context": "CriticalQueueVolumeComb",
        "inputEvents": [
          {
            "name": "QueueContextUpdate",
            "filterExpression": "QueueContextUpdate.volume>1000",
            "consumptionPolicy": "Consume",
            "instanceSelectionPolicy": "First"
          }
        ],
        "computedVariables": [],
        "evaluationPolicy": "Immediate",
        "cardinalityPolicy": "Single",
        "internalSegmentation": [],
        "derivedEvents": [
          {
            "name": "QueueVolumeHigh",
            "reportParticipants": false,
            "expressions": {
              "OccurrenceTime": "QueueContextUpdate.DetectionTime",
              "Duration": "0",
              "AffectedEntity": "QueueContextUpdate.entityId",
              "AffectedEntityType": "QueueContextUpdate.entityType",
              "EventType": "\"QueueVolumeHigh\"",
              "EventSeverity": "\"Critical\"",
              "AffectedEntityVolume": "QueueContextUpdate.volume"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "MissingQueueDataRule",
        "description": "Detect when the scripts stop working and sending queue data",
        "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
        "epaType": "Absence",
        "context": "MissingQueueDataWindow",
        "inputEvents": [
          {
            "name": "QueueContextUpdate",
            "alias": "Q1",
            "consumptionPolicy": "Consume",
            "instanceSelectionPolicy": "First"
          }
        ],
        "computedVariables": [],
        "evaluationPolicy": "Deferred",
        "cardinalityPolicy": "Single",
        "internalSegmentation": [],
        "derivedEvents": [
          {
            "name": "MissingQueueData",
            "reportParticipants": false,
            "expressions": {
              "Certainty": "1.0",
              "Duration": "0",
              "EventSeverity": "\"Warning\""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "contexts": {
      "temporal": [
        {
          "name": "Always",
          "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
          "type": "TemporalInterval",
          "atStartup": true,
          "neverEnding": true,
          "initiators": [],
          "terminators": []
        },
        {
          "name": "CriticalQueueVolumeWindow",
          "description": "Start when queue volume > 1000, ends in 30seconds",
          "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
          "createdBy": "Pedro",
          "type": "TemporalInterval",
          "atStartup": false,
          "neverEnding": false,
          "initiators": [
            {
              "initiatorType": "Event",
              "initiatorPolicy": "Ignore",
              "name": "QueueContextUpdate",
              "condition": "QueueContextUpdate.volume>1000"
            }
          ],
          "terminators": [
            {
              "terminatorType": "Event",
              "terminatorPolicy": "First",
              "terminationType": "Terminate",
              "name": "QueueContextUpdate",
              "condition": " QueueContextUpdate.volume<500"
            },
            {
              "terminatorType": "RelativeTime",
              "terminationType": "Terminate",
              "relativeTime": "300000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "MissingQueueDataWindow",
          "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
          "type": "TemporalInterval",
          "atStartup": false,
          "neverEnding": false,
          "initiators": [
            {
              "initiatorType": "Event",
              "initiatorPolicy": "Add",
              "name": "QueueContextUpdate"
            }
          ],
          "terminators": [
            {
              "terminatorType": "RelativeTime",
              "terminationType": "Terminate",
              "relativeTime": "10000"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "segmentation": [
        {
          "name": "QueueID",
          "description": "Treat objects as distinct based on entityID",
          "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
          "createdBy": "Pedro",
          "participantEvents": [
            {
              "name": "QueueContextUpdate",
              "expression": "QueueContextUpdate.entityId"
            },
            {
              "name": "QueueVolumeHigh",
              "expression": "QueueVolumeHigh.AffectedEntity"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "composite": [
        {
          "name": "CriticalQueueVolumeComb",
          "createdDate": "Wed Jan 27 2016",
          "temporalContexts": [
            {
              "name": "CriticalQueueVolumeWindow"
            }
          ],
          "segmentationContexts": [
            {
              "name": "QueueID"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "consumers": [
      {
        "name": "DeviceReport",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "type": "File",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "filename",
            "value": "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sample/SentinelMonitor_DeviceReport.txt"
          },
          {
            "name": "formatter",
            "value": "json"
          },
          {
            "name": "delimiter",
            "value": ";"
          },
          {
            "name": "tagDataSeparator",
            "value": "="
          },
          {
            "name": "SendingDelay",
            "value": "1000"
          }
        ],
        "events": [
          {
            "name": "Device"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "QueueReport",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "type": "File",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "filename",
            "value": "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sample/SentinelMonitor_QueueReport.txt"
          },
          {
            "name": "formatter",
            "value": "json"
          },
          {
            "name": "delimiter",
            "value": ";"
          },
          {
            "name": "tagDataSeparator",
            "value": "="
          },
          {
            "name": "SendingDelay",
            "value": "1000"
          }
        ],
        "events": [
          {
            "name": "Queue"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "DeviceContextUpdateReport",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "type": "File",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "filename",
            "value": "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sample/SentinelMonitor_DeviceContextUpdateReport.txt"
          },
          {
            "name": "formatter",
            "value": "json"
          },
          {
            "name": "delimiter",
            "value": ";"
          },
          {
            "name": "tagDataSeparator",
            "value": "="
          },
          {
            "name": "SendingDelay",
            "value": "1000"
          }
        ],
        "events": [
          {
            "name": "DeviceContextUpdate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "QueueContextUpdateReport",
        "createdDate": "Thu Nov 12 2015",
        "type": "File",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "filename",
            "value": "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sample/SentinelMonitor_QueueContextUpdateReport.txt"
          },
          {
            "name": "formatter",
            "value": "json"
          },
          {
            "name": "delimiter",
            "value": ";"
          },
          {
            "name": "tagDataSeparator",
            "value": "="
          },
          {
            "name": "SendingDelay",
            "value": "1000"
          }
        ],
        "events": [
          {
            "name": "QueueContextUpdate"
          },
          {
            "name": "QueueVolumeHigh"
          },
          {
            "name": "MissingQueueData"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "producers": [],
    "name": "SentinelMonitor"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the initiator of the temporal context that your EPA is using is the `QueueContextUpdate` event that you are looking to find. Since this event doesn't arrive, the context is not initiated... and the EPA is not active at all...

For testing, I would suggest to change the initiator of the temporal context to `At Startup` and try to run again.

Later, you will need to decide what is the right definition of this temporal context, and what is the right initiator. Maybe you want to set this temporal context to be of `Sliding Time Window` type?